# Pull Out Packet Data From String And Store To Array

Tags: python-2.7

I am pulling packet data from a console application as a string in the following format:-

AABBCCDDAABBCCDDAABBCCDD

Each character is a byte, and each block i.e. AA is actually a single value that needs to be joined to form a ctypes.c_ushort.

I want to then have this data in 4 arrays - one containing all the AA's, one all the BB's etc.

I suspect there is probably a very easy way of doing this, but lots of trying and plugging search terms into Google hasn't managed to bring up quite what I want so hoping someone on here might be able to help.

Thanks in advance for any help given. Dave

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
data = "AABBCCDDAABBCCDDAABBCCDD"
Aarr = []
Barr = []
Carr = []
Darr = []
MasterArr = [Aarr, Darr, Carr, Barr]

for i in xrange(len(data) / 2):
    MasterArr[(4 - i) % 4].append(data[i * 2:(i * 2) + 2])

print MasterArr
```

Obviosly lines 2-6 could be simplified to:

```
MasterArr = [[], [], [], []]
```

I made it longer so it would be esier to understand.

EDIT: made it simplier to understand